# Can't get Excel Custom Ribbon Callbacks to work

Tags: xml, vba, excel, callback

I'm trying to create a button that I want to show on my custom tab that indicates whether the user has the most up-to-date version of my Excel Add-on at work. I plan on checking for if they have the most recent version by writing the original `Last Modified` of the `xlam` file to a file whenever the user opens an Excel instance. Then on the `Workbook_Open` event I'll initiate an `OnTime` action to compare the date & time written in the file to that of the public file's `Last Modified` every 15 minutes. This is in case the users have any Excel instances open at the time I deploy an update since they'll have to close all instances, then reopen Excel in order to have the most recent version.

Anyway, having that background, I'm having trouble with callbacks for the Status button. My idea is to have the button show a green check and have a label of *Up-to-date* when excel is initially opened because in that case Excel will have the current version instead of a cached version that's saved in temp files. Then, if when the `updateCheck` sub fires it finds a newer version is available I want to change the button image to an Exclamation Point and the label to *Update Now*.

The problem is, it seems whenever I try to put ANY callbacks on the button element (other than the default `onAction`) by using the Custom UI Editor the ribbon doesn't show up anymore in Excel. If I don't have any callbacks on the button and only have the `onLoad` callback on the ribbon itself, then the ribbon shows up fine when opening Excel and the `onLoad` event fires (tested with `MsgBox`). Below is my XML and VBA code

In Module1:

```
Public myRibbonUI As IRibbonUI

'Callback for customUI.onLoad
Sub RibbonLoaded(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set myRibbonUI = ribbon
    MsgBox ("Ribbon Loaded")
End Sub

'Callback for customButton getImage
Sub GetButtonImage(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    MsgBox (returnedVal)
End Sub

'Callback for customButton getLabel
Sub GetButtonLabel(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    MsgBox (returnedVal)
End Sub

'Callback for customButton onAction
Sub ButtonClick(control As IRibbonControl)
    'Invalidates the cache of a single control
    MsgBox ("Fire!")
    myRibbonUI.InvalidateControl ("customButton")
End Sub
```

XML Code:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="RibbonLoaded">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="customTab" label="Custom Tab">
                <group id="customGroup" label="Custom Group">
                    <button id="customButton" label="Custom Button" imageMso="HappyFace" size="large" onAction="ButtonClick" getImage="GetButtonImage" getLabel="GetButtonLabel"/>
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

With the above code I was simply just trying to see if I could get the callbacks working (which I couldn't).

**Finally, the Question:**
What am I doing wrong? To make sure it's not just an issue when using it in an `xlam` file I tried doing with just an `xlsm` file and I still get the same result.

**Follow-Up Question:**
How do I change the image to another `imageMso`? I've seen people change custom images using image, but do I also use image to change to another `imageMso` or do I use `imageMso` in place of image in the callback procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have both `label` and `getLabel`, or `image` and `getImage` in the same XML button node. Didn't the Custom UI Editor flag this when you checked the code?

Comment: I actually didn't know there was a validate feature until yesterday *headdesk*. Also, this is my first time working with callbacks. Thanks, that worked though after removing the `label` and `image` tags!